# Timeout Directive in Service Scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Yallo,

I have the below snippet.

I would like an explanation and perhaps a better solution provided as to why this doesn't work I have suspicions. First I bound the `$scope.message` to the service var equivalent `messageToggle()`. then I triggered the timer function `timer`. but the `$scope.message` doesn't update with it. The reason I am trying to have the method in a service is because I use the timer a decent amount through my code.

Angular

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])

    app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, Service){
      $scope.status = "words"
      $scope.message = Service.getMessage()
      Service.timer()
    })

    app.service('Service', function($timeout){
      var messageToggle = false

      return {
        getMessage: function(){
          return messageToggle
        },
        timer: function(){
          messageToggle = true;
          $timeout(function (messageToggle = false) {}, 2000)
        }
      }
    })
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp">
      <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <span ng-show="message"> {{status}} </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing we need to change here is to use `angular.factory` instead of `angular.service` as we are returning an object, service is a constructor function and factory is not so here is difference between the syntax of both:

```
app.service('myService', function() {

  // service is just a constructor function

  this.sayHello = function(name) {
     return "Hi " + name + "!";
  };
});

app.factory('myFactory', function() {

  // factory returns an object
  // you can run some code before

  return {
    sayHello : function(name) {
      return "Hi " + name + "!";
    }
  }
});
```

Now, second change is to notify the change in `messageToggle`from service to controller, to do so one option is to handle the promise returned from `$timeout`.

So here is the syntax:

```
var getPromise = function () {
    return $timeout(function() {
        // logic here
      }, 2000);
}
```

and in the caller function, we need to handle it that is:

```
 getPromise().then(
        function(success){
       },function(error){
       });
```

And lastly here is the working plunker for your code:

> https://plnkr.co/edit/4PDuY3KgwCe7F5Ys12A6?p=preview

Where status is visible for 2000msecs and then gets invisible.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because `$scope.message = Service.getMessage()` does not make `$scope.message` reference the `Service.getMessage()` value, but merely ends up copying it. Thus, although the `Service.getMessage()` value changes, the copy in `$scope.message` does not, and the angular machinery can not pick up the change.

You need to propagate the change. One alternative:

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, Service){
  $scope.status = "words"
  $scope.message = Service.getMessage()
  Service.timer()

  $scope.$watch(function() {return Service.getMessage()}, function(message){
    $scope.message = message;
  });
})
```

Here we are adding a “manual” watch which will update your scope variable `message` upon change of the watched value `Service.getMessage()`.

[Live example](https://plnkr.co/edit/2tvc2jfQw9oaVZGSjhnp?p=preview)